# Leaflet js remove one layer, add another layer and filter by variable of first layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, leaflet, layer

i have an leaflet map serving data over two urls out of a database. i use django and django-leaflet. python 3.5, postgresql 9.6.

layerA is showed when loading the page. opening the popup of layerA i want have the possibility to load layerB by clicking in the popup of an item in LayerA. Items in LayerB belong to certain items in LayerA connected by foreign key.

here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zt56nmog/11/

heres my code:

```
function map_init_basic (map, options) {
  urlA = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.A"   // Geojson
  urlB = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data.B"  // Geojson

     layerA = L.geoJson(null, {
                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                     return L.marker(latlng, {icon: hvIcon});
                    },
                onEachFeature:  function( feature, layer) {
                     popupText = "button to call layerA" + "<button id='theirFlats' type='button' class='btn btn-link' onclick='getLayerB(\""+feature.id+"\");'>show layerB:</button>";
                     layer.bindPopup(popupText);
                }
              });


     layerB = L.geoJson(null, {
                filter: function(feature, layer) {
                     {return feature.properties.id_hv == id_layerA;};
                },
                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                     return L.marker(latlng, {icon: whgIcon});
                }
              });


        $.getJSON(urlA, function(data){
                layerA.addData(data);
        });

        layerA.addTo(map);

} // end map_init

function getLayerB(id_layerA){
        alert(id_layerA); // alerts the right id
        layerA.remove();  // works, removes the layerA

        alert(urlB)

        $.getJSON(urlB, function(data){
                layerB.addData(data);
                console.log(data);
                });

        layerB.addTo(map);
        alert(layerB)
        map.fitBounds(layerB);

        }
```

i get the following error:

TypeError: t is undefined

Comment: error said that you don't declare id_layerB variable, please check the code because you really missed it.

Comment: oh sorry, yes that was a typ-o. meant to be id_layerA. but the other error is there and i dont know what t is.

Comment: Could you compose jsfiddle for these case? it will be easier to debug and validate ideas

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zt56nmog/13/ thanks for looking at it

Comment: i've added the function to window and all starts working

`window.getLayerB = getLayerB;`

https://jsfiddle.net/2bufypa2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add getLayerB to window to make it accessible to onclick handler for popup

```js
urlA = {"features":[{"id":1736,"type":"Feature","properties":{"hv_city_name":"Berlin","hv_id":1736},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.299364,52.487194]}},{"id":2814,"type":"Feature","properties":{"hv_city_name":"Berlin","hv_id":2814},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.627012,52.540632]}}]}

urlB = {"features":[{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.41001,52.49778]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":100176801},"id":100176801,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.6312,52.4528]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":100195258},"id":100195258,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.42556,52.53958]},"properties":{"id_hv":1736,"whg_scout_id":93580383},"id":93580383,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.41757,52.55054]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":66425039},"id":66425039,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.37035,52.53373]},"properties":{"id_hv":1736,"whg_scout_id":100201644},"id":100201644,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.24678,52.50916]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":100205048},"id":100205048,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.3163,52.52065]},"properties":{"id_hv":1736,"whg_scout_id":99870716},"id":99870716,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.33467,52.46926]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":99350260},"id":99350260,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.33144,52.48821]},"properties":{"id_hv":1736,"whg_scout_id":100031435},"id":100031435,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.2003,52.51963]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":100183131},"id":100183131,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.46024,52.50881]},"properties":{"id_hv":1736,"whg_scout_id":100206080},"id":100206080,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.29768,52.62473]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":98474448},"id":98474448,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.48831,52.51692]},"properties":{"id_hv":1736,"whg_scout_id":100183115},"id":100183115,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.47752,52.60434]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":100171391},"id":100171391,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.32684,52.46749]},"properties":{"id_hv":1736,"whg_scout_id":100180115},"id":100180115,"type":"Feature"},{"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[13.37858,52.50024]},"properties":{"id_hv":2814,"whg_scout_id":88565013},"id":88565013,"type":"Feature"}]}




var OpenStreetMap_BlackAndWhite = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
 maxZoom: 18,
 attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
});

var map = L.map('map')
    .setView([52.5, 13.5], 10)
    .addLayer(OpenStreetMap_BlackAndWhite);

        
        
layerA = L.geoJson(urlA, {
                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                     return L.marker(latlng);
                    },
                onEachFeature:  function( feature, layer) {
                     popupText = "button to call layerB" + "<button id='belongs2A' type='button' class='btn btn-link' onclick='getLayerB(\""+feature.id+"\");'>show layerB:</button>";
                     layer.bindPopup(popupText);
                },
                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                     return L.circle(latlng, {color: 'red'});
                }
              });

function getLayerB(id_layerA){
        alert(id_layerA); // alerts the right id
        layerA.remove();  // works, removes the layerA
        
        layerB = L.geoJson(urlB, {
                filter: function(feature, layer) {
                     {return feature.properties.id_hv == parseInt(id_layerA);};
                },
                pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
                     return L.circle(latlng, {color: 'blue'});
                }
              });
        map.addLayer(layerB);
        }

// i have made reference getLayerB to window to make it accessible for onclick handler
// which can call only global functions
window.getLayerB = getLayerB;



map.addLayer(layerA);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.2.0/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="map"></div>
```